# Using playonlinux 4.2.2 results in error message

Tags: wine, 14.04, playonlinux

When I do start any program in playonlinux or install additional components you get back the following message:

```
Error in POL_Call
Function POL_Install_ does not exist!
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to:

```
sudo apt-get purge playonlinux
```

And then:

```
sudo apt-get install playonlinux
```

Does that work? If not, please post the full console output.